# Laravel Error Migrating Darabase: BadMethodCallException Method \Blueprint::url does not exist

Tags: sql, laravel, database-migration, rollback

I'm very new to Laravel so if this is obvious then I'm sorry but I don't know what it means. I was simply trying to add a feature that allowed the user to add a new post .I was having an issue so I tried a rollback which was fine but when I tried to migrate again I got this:

[image]

Here is the create post table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('thought');
            $table->url('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Here is my Post.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $gaurded = [];

    public function user(){ 

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

PostsController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){

        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(){

        $data = request()->validate([
            'title',
            'thought',
            'image',
            'url'
        ]);

        auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

And I have no idea what to do. Since I don't know what is going on I really don't know what other info you might need but if there is anything else that would be helpful in solving this please let me know. Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: plz post your post_table code

Comment: post your code in migration

Comment: @ColePerry no, I means the migration file's code.

Comment: It should be there. Check again. @TsaiKoga

Comment: url is not a datatype in laravel migration. change it as string. for reference please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: change to `$table->string('url')->nullable();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you have used "url" datatype in the migration file and there is no such method in the **"Blueprint"** class of laravel.So that's why error is occured.